# input type required without a form tag

Tags: javascript, html

It only seems to work if the input type is in a form. Possible made a validation over javascript and not using the form tag? 
Expected: if the text field is empty and i click submit it should come the message the the field is empty. Only submit if the field is field out

my script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr><td><input type="text" size"30" placeholder="put id"  id="source" required>
<button type="submit" class="formButton" id="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" style="border:none" size="40" id="target" class="form" onClick="myFunct()" required></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" style="border:none" size="40" id="target" class="form21" onClick="myFunct()" required></td></tr>

<script>
$(".formButton").click(function() {
 $(".form21").show();
});
</script>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
 var source = $('#source').val();
$('#target').val('text' + ' text');
}); 
</script>
```

What i tired, but seams not to work

```
<script>
function  myFunct(){
if (document.getElementById('source').validity.valid) { alert('missing name'); return }
</script>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: _What_ only seems to work if... ? -- _How_ does it not seem to work?  What did you expect, what is actually happening? _"input type required without a form tag"_ but you _have_ a type in `<input type="text"...>` so do you mean something different when you say "type"?

Comment: Expected: if the text field is empty and i click submit it should come the message the the field is empty. Only submit if the field is field out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$('#target').val('text + ' text');` , the quotes are not properly closed and there is no text variable.

So this should be `$('#target').val('text' + source );`

2. In myFunct , there is no closing brace for the function.
3. ID is unique for a page. So do not use same ID's for multiple elements. In this example , target is used twice.
4. Reg the element's validity, when the element is invalid, the valid property will be false. So for the alert message , the condition should be `(!document.getElementById('source').validity.valid)` (i.e) to check if the element is *not* valid .
5. Submit button's click handler does not invoke myFunct func. So with the current code , the validator function will be called when the input element's with class "form" and "form21" . If you want the validation to be done on submit click , the validation code should be present for the button submit click handler.

Comment: Thank you for all explanation.
Could you may made an example how it will be correctly. I tried but i failed. 

how to you would solve the problem with `(!document.getElementById('source').validity.valid)`

Can you may made an example? thank you